# Export one Frame of an animation as Collade in Twinmotion

Tags: export, collada

I want to export one frame of an Animation in Blender as Collada file to [Twinmotion](https://www.twinmotion.com/en-US/faq).

When I view the exported model in Microsoft's 3D Viewer, the correct model is displayed. But if I add that to Twinmotion now, the standard model will be added. Can someone tell me, where my mistake is?

[image]

The 3D Viewer and Twinmotion do not support animations. For this reason I shifted the timeline in Blender until I got the still image I wanted.
Then I loaded the model into Twinmotion without animation. However, the modified model is not shown there, but the original model without the timeline adjustment.
I thought I did something wrong when exporting and checked the model in the 3D viewer. To my surprise, it was displayed correctly there.
This actually shows me that Twinmotion has a problem reading files that come from an animation.
So the question for me is: how do I export a single frame of an animation so that only that frame is present in the file and no longer the animation?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm a Blender user and this is about problems in Blender not other software... so I'm missing a lot of information here to guess what the problem is. What were your settings on export? How exactly did you try to export a certain frame? Does Collada support animations/rigs? Does Windows 3D viewer support animations/rigs? Does Twinmotion support animations/rigs? And maybe even more things worth knowing?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I only have to delete the animation-bones of the model. Then it only exports the 3D data and no longer the information about the animation.